# cakephp 2.1 Facebook Connect with Auth

Tags: facebook, authentication, cakephp-2.1

Can any one help me in getting facebook connect working in my cakephp 2.1 app.
Now I am able to user authentication with Auth, I need to add facebook connect to the same.
where users can register themselves by filling a user form or they can sign up through facebook. Googled a lot but not able to get it working.

A tutorial link or an example with complete code will be very useful, I am new to cakephp.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using this plugin and it's working well with my Cake 2.1

https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin

There is a readme on that page ;)

Comment: I'm not able to make my other friends login through their facebook account. Only I am able to login. Is this the problem with my app Key...?? An error says like this -> "An error occurred. Please try again later." later they able to login into their facebook account but not to my app. please help